# Open CV memory stacked (not released properly)

Tags: objective-c, opencv, uiimage

I am using 3rd party library for image processing, this method seems to be the cause of large memory usage (+30MB) everytime it executed, and it won't release properly. Repeated use of it ends up crashing the app (memory overload). The image used is directly from camera of my iP6.

```
+ (UIImage *)UIImageFromCVMat:(cv::Mat)cvMat
{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cvMat.data length:cvMat.elemSize() * cvMat.total()];

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;

    if (cvMat.elemSize() == 1) {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    } else {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    }

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(cvMat.cols,                                     // Width
                                        cvMat.rows,                                     // Height
                                        8,                                              // Bits per component
                                        8 * cvMat.elemSize(),                           // Bits per pixel
                                        cvMat.step[0],                                  // Bytes per row
                                        colorSpace,                                     // Colorspace
                                        kCGImageAlphaNone | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,  // Bitmap info flags
                                        provider,                                       // CGDataProviderRef
                                        NULL,                                           // Decode
                                        false,                                          // Should interpolate
                                        kCGRenderingIntentDefault);                     // Intent

    // UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return image;
}
```

I suspect the problem is here: `(__bridge CFDataRef)data`. I cant use CFRelease on it cause it make app crash. Project is running with ARC.

**EDIT:**

It seems the same code is also in openCV official website:
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/ios/image_manipulation/image_manipulation.html

Gah!

**EDIT 2**
Here is the code how I use it (actually below code is also a part of the 3rd party lib, but i added some lines).

```
 cv::Mat undistorted = cv::Mat( cvSize(maxWidth,maxHeight), CV_8UC4); // here nothing
        cv::Mat original = [MMOpenCVHelper cvMatFromUIImage:_adjustedImage]; // here +30MB

        //NSLog(@"%f %f %f %f",ptBottomLeft.x,ptBottomRight.x,ptTopRight.x,ptTopLeft.x);
        cv::warpPerspective(original, undistorted,
                            cv::getPerspectiveTransform(src, dst), cvSize(maxWidth, maxHeight)); // here +16MB 



        _cropRect.hidden=YES;

        @autoreleasepool {
            _sourceImageView.image=[MMOpenCVHelper UIImageFromCVMat:undistorted]; // here +15MB (PROBLEM)
        }         

        original.release(); // here -30MB (THIS IS OK)
        undistorted.release(); // here -16MB (ok)
```

Comment: Hey anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: I tried using this code with .png image of dimensions 651x481. I didn't see any memory leak. It used 0.1 MB to do the processing. After the processing, it released properly. May I know, how you are using the function.

Comment: Have you tried to run it under Instruments Memory Leak tool? Which data type is actually leaked? NSData? UIImage? something else?

Comment: I do a step by step process and manage to pinpoint the problem. I add code above with comment where the problem happens. As u see problem is with UIImageFromCVMat. And also problem from  warpPerspective

Comment: Guess it is a hard subject since not many people knows OpenCV that well. What I found is that most answer for the similar problem involves putting @autoreleasepool where this method is used. But seems to be not releasing memory either. As temporary workaround I resize the image fed to this method by half. At least app will last longer before it crash finally.

Comment: I have the same problem with **MatToUIImage**. I just copy the **ios_conversions.mm** of latest version to my project and modify the functions to class methods. You can have a try. [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43975953/opencv-mattouiimage-causes-memory-leak)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess it is a hard subject since not many people knows OpenCV that well. What I found is that most answer for the similar problem involves putting @autoreleasepool where this method is used. But seems to be not releasing memory either.

As temporary solution I resize the image fed to this method by half. At least app will last longer before it crash finally. It just works.