# OpenCV MatToUIImage causes memory leak

Tags: ios, opencv, memory-leaks, ios10

My project is working with openCV for iOS(2.4.9). And I found function **MatToUIImage** which will cause memory leaks, and it only occurs on iOS 10.X.

After I updated this function(2.4.9) to latest(3.2.0) version everything got worked. The only difference is **CGBitmapInfo**.

So can anyone tell me why?

**2.4.9**

```
UIImage* MatToUIImage(const cv::Mat& image) {

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:image.data
                                  length:image.elemSize()*image.total()];

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;

    if (image.elemSize() == 1) {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    } else {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    }

    CGDataProviderRef provider =
            CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);

    // Creating CGImage from cv::Mat
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(image.cols,
                                        image.rows,
                                        8,
                                        8 * image.elemSize(),
                                        image.step.p[0],
                                        colorSpace,
                                        kCGImageAlphaNone|
                                        kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,
                                        provider,
                                        NULL,
                                        false,
                                        kCGRenderingIntentDefault
                                        );


    // Getting UIImage from CGImage
    UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return finalImage;
}
```

**3.2.0**

```
UIImage* MatToUIImage(const cv::Mat& image) {

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:image.data
                                  length:image.elemSize()*image.total()];

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;

    if (image.elemSize() == 1) {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    } else {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    }

    CGDataProviderRef provider =
            CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);

    // Preserve alpha transparency, if exists
    bool alpha = image.channels() == 4;
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = (alpha ? kCGImageAlphaLast : kCGImageAlphaNone) | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;

    // Creating CGImage from cv::Mat
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(image.cols,
                                        image.rows,
                                        8,
                                        8 * image.elemSize(),
                                        image.step.p[0],
                                        colorSpace,
                                        bitmapInfo,
                                        provider,
                                        NULL,
                                        false,
                                        kCGRenderingIntentDefault
                                        );


    // Getting UIImage from CGImage
    UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return finalImage;
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at the recent answer update!

Answer (score 1):

**Important update (5.06.2017)** Finally, to perform `CFRelease` manually turned out to be bad idea as it can raise more troubles than solve! Though, it gave me a clue that leaks are somehow connected with `NSData` (not-)releasing.

I noticed that it's released automatically as expected with ARC when called from block in background thread, like that:

```
- (void)runInBackgroundWithImageBuffer:(CVImageBufferRef)imageBuffer
                              callback:(void (^)())callback {
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        [self processImageBuffer:imageBuffer];
        if (callback != nil) {
            callback();
        }
    });
}

- (void)previewOpenCVImage:(cv::Mat *)image {
    UIImage *preview = MatToUIImage(*image);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // _imagePreview has (UIImageView *) type
        [_imagePreview setImage:preview];
    });
}
```

<del>**I can confirm that for iPhone Simulator**. Seems like current `MatToUIImage` implementation causes memory leaks on simulator. And I can't reproduce it on device.</del>

<del>For some reason they are not detected by profiler but memory usage just blows up after multiple calls.</del>

<del>I've added some tweaks to make it working:</del>

1. <del>Add line `CFRelease((CFTypeRef)data)` before returning final image</del>
2. <del>When image is not necessary we need to perform `CFRelease(image.CGImage)` and probably `CFRelease((CFTypeRef)image)`</del>

<del>Hope that helps. Actually I don't completely understand why this is happening, who is holding references and why do we need to manually perform release.</del>

Comment: Thank you very much! You give a real solution, while I just replaced the file and left it away... I will test it anyway. But I still don't know why changing *CGBitmapInfo* will fix the bug. It's really weird.

Comment: Actually things are much more weird. The behaviour is different not only between device and simulator. It also differs between iPhone versions of simulator. For example, on iPhone 6 (simulator) `CFRelease(oldImage.CGImage)` is needed but `CFRelease((CFTypeRef)data)` will crash.